# ExDoc: getting source links working with private repository

Tags: elixir, documentation-generation

I'm trying to generate documentation for my project.

I've added `{:ex_doc, "~> 0.16", only: :dev, runtime: false}` to my `deps`, set `source_url` to my repository and run `mix docs`.

I'm using Github Enterprise so my setting is something like this: `source_url: "https://my.private.repo/adam/projname"`

However, in the generated docs, all of the links to the source point directly to `https://my.private.repo/adam/projname` rather than the the relvant file and line number.

An example of what I want to do:

https://hexdocs.pm/ex_doc/Mix.Tasks.Docs.html

The link at the top-right of this file links to `https://github.com/elixir-lang/ex_doc/blob/v0.18.3/lib/mix/tasks/docs.ex#L1`

In my generated docs, every link just links to `https://my.private.repo/adam/projname`.

I've tried setting `source_ref` to `master`, but this made no difference.

How do I get `ExDoc` to generate properly specific links to the source code?

Here's a simplified version of my `mix.exs` file:

```elixir
defmodule ProjectName.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :project_name,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      deps: deps(),

      # Docs
      name: "ProjectName",
      source_url: "https://my.private.repo/adam/projname"
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you try appending a `/` to the `source_url`?

Comment: Yes I did that, the same result (the links are all directly to the `source_url`, now with slash added).

Comment: Is your domain one of the following: `github.com`, `bitbucket.com` or `gitlab.com`? If not, [ex_docs won't be able to auto-guess the correct path](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ex_doc/blob/master/lib/ex_doc.ex#L176-L183)

Comment: No, it's not. That'll be why then. Thanks for pointing it out. I guess I should raise an issue / PR for this.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer , there is a `source_url_pattern` field for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ex_doc` will only automatically figure out where to find the file when you're using one of the following domains as `source_url`. [ex_docs source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ex_doc/blob/b8205d5a97d96e8e985895da88c45cc83357797b/lib/ex_doc.ex#L176-L183)

- `github.com`
- `bitbucket.com`
- `gitlab.com`

In the cases where the domain is different, you will have to supply a `source_url_pattern` in the `docs` section of your `mix.exs` file

```
  def project do
    [
      app: :test_exdoc,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.7-dev",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      source_url: "https://yourprivate-repo.com/adam/projname",
      deps: deps(),
      docs: [
        source_url_pattern: "https://yourprivate-repo.com/adam/projname/blob/master/%{path}#L%{line}"
      ]
    ]
  end
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. :-) `source_url_pattern` needs `/blob` before `/master/` (not enough characters for me to edit your answer myself).